# afterburner.fx get view from node

Tags: javafx, mvp

i've been trying to get the grasp of afterburner.fx for few days now but i cant figure out this problem. please help

there are three tabs in a tab pane

```
tabPane.getTabs().get(0).setContent(new FirstView().getView());
tabPane.getTabs().get(1).setContent(new SecondView().getView());
tabPane.getTabs().get(2).setContent(new ThirdView().getView());
```

these are not named firstview, secondview etc. it's for demonstration...

now each of these views have a reload method:

```
firstView.reload()
secondView.reload()
thirdView.reload()
```

and i have setup a listener for tab changes so that i can reload these views once they come into view

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    newValue.getView().reload(); // of course this cant be done like this
})
```

how to reload the view of the tab once it comes into view.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add listeners to the individual tabs instead of to the tab pane:

```
FirstView firstView = new FirstView();
Tab tab0 = tabs.getTabs().get(0);
tab0.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    if (isSelected) {
        firstView.reload();
    }
});
tab0.setContent(firstView.getView());

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find a work around for this. i made two new classes, one that extends FXMLView and another that extends Tab.

```
public abstract class ReloadableView extends FXMLView {

    public abstract void reload();

}
```

and

```
public class ReloadingTab<V extends ReloadableView> extends Tab {

    private V view;

    public ReloadingTab(String text, V view) {
        super(text, view.getView());
        this.view = view;
    }

    public V getView() {
        return view;
    }

}
```

and finally added the listener

```
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        ReloadingTab tab = (ReloadingTab) newValue;
        tab.getView().reload();
    });
```

sorry if my question didnt make any sense. i hope someone finds this useful.